# Oneliner for outputting to file only if string is matched (bash)?

Tags: bash, text-processing, io-redirection, io

I am making a script where I curl a URL and output to a file like this:

```
curl http://example.com/$1 > $1
```

Is there any way to make it dismiss anything that doesn't include, say `<head>`? I could of course do something like this:

```
web="$(curl http://example.com/$1)"
if $(echo "$web" | grep -q "<head>"); then
printf "$web" > "$1"
fi
```

But this script may potentially be ran very many times, so I would like to save time.

Comment: Are you trying to catch cases where the URL does not return a valid HTML page, or are you trying to catch HTML error responses?

Comment: @datUser It always returns a valid page, but I only want to output some valid pages to a file (like if it includes "<head"> in my given example). The 4 line script I made works for this purpose, but I am looking for a shorter, faster alternative.

Comment: shorter does not mean faster.  Any script can be one line by using `;` excessively.

Comment: @Jesse_b True, but I was thinking that something involving maybe a double pipe (`||`) or something instead of `if` would be faster

Answer (score 1):

Just save it to a file and delete it if it does not include that tag:

```
curl "http://example.com/$1" >"$1"
! grep -qF '<head>' "$1" && rm "$1"
```

Or, if you want to complicate it slightly,

```
if curl "http://example.com/$1" | tee "$1" | ! grep -qF '<head>'
then
    rm "$1"
fi
```

Or do *all* the fetching first, *then* go through the resulting files and delete them,

```
mkdir outdir  # assuming this is not pre-existing

# iterates over all positional parameters
for path do
    curl "http://example.com/$path" >outdir/"$path"
done

find outdir -type f ! -exec grep -qF '<head>' {} \; -delete
```

But this would only work if you want to get e.g. all the known files under a fixed path.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
grep -hIz '<head>' < <(curl -s "http://example.com/$1") > "$1" || rm "$1"
```

This will supress all output *unless* it contains `<head>` in which case it will print *all* output.  If no match is made an empty file will be created anyway so it will need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
curl "http://example.com/$1" | tee temp | grep -q derp && cat temp; rm temp
```

Saves curl output to file and pipes the output to grep which then searches for `derp` in the output and if found outputs the content of the curl command to stdout, if `derp` is not found, there is no script output. The temp file is then removed.

Not sure you can do this without 'buffering' to a file, since `bash` does not have a way to conditionally buffer output from a command.